# Excel export in JavaScript not working using Blob

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have some javascript problem. I'm struggling to download a file in xlsx format. In backend works everything fine - file is downloaded using for example swagger.

My code:

```
private async downloadDocumentTemplate(report: string) {
            this.fileLoading = true;
            try {
                const result = await this.$store.dispatch("report/downloadDocument", report);

                const blob = new Blob([result], {type: "application/octet-stream"});

                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.addEventListener("loadend", function() {

                });
                reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);


                console.log("blob contnet : " + blob.type);

                FileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'report.xlsx');
            } catch (ex) {
                this.$store.commit("app/showErrorPopup", ex);
            }
            this.fileLoading = false;
        }
```

After downloading file from the web and file is open automatically and  I am experiencing an error that reads:

"We found a problem with some content .xlsx. Do you want us to try and recover as much as we can?" e

Comment: Hello, could you add some more info. What is the exact problem because you say you have a problem but it works in the backend. So where does it not work and also what is the error you get and what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @mrdeadsven I added more details

Answer (score 0):

I had some similar issue. The problem in my case was how I parsed the Excel data. The script was putting wrong formatted information.

If downloading the file to the computer works, there must be an error in your code which parses the excel data.

Comment: so why my solution work in swagger? How to check if  my code putting correctly formatted information?

Comment: Could you provide the code which generates the report variable?

Comment: report is just a name of report like XYZ.